# remove music from my device in Itunes only

Tags: macos

I just want to remove all music from the my device file in Itunes. I do not want to change anything in my Iphone, just the content of the my device file.

Comment: What is the "my device file"?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes on the computer is the 'Master' device.

Anything you discard from there will be removed from your iPhone the next time you sync it.
- unless it is purchased through the iTunes Store, allowing you to re-download directly to the iPhone at a later date.